# Counting vowel and consonant in a string

Tags: c#, string, visual-studio, cons

```
            int total = 0;
            int wordCount = 0, index = 0;
            var vowels = new HashSet<char> { 'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u' };
            var consonants = new HashSet<char> { 'b', 'c', 'd', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'v', 'x' };

            for (int i = 0; i < sentence.Length; i++)

                    if (vowels.Contains(sentence[i]))
                    {
                        total++;
                    }
                    else if (consonants.Contains(sentence[i]))
                    {
                        total++;
                    }

                }
                Console.WriteLine("Your total number of vowels is: {0}", total);
                Console.WriteLine("Number of consonants: {0}", total);
                Console.ReadLine();
`
```

This is my code. When I run my code, it accurately tells me how many vowels there are, but it does not tell me the number of consonants. It just copied the number of vowels.

Comment: do you realize that this is the second time you ask and.. it had the exact same code that prints the same `total` variable..? as a place to start, count your consonant and vowels in different variable.

Comment: So `total` is the number of vowels and the number of consonants? How does that work?

Comment: @John3136, looks like op did not read (or tried to understand) his own code.. **When I run my code, it accurately tells me how many vowels there are, but it does not tell me the number of consonants. It just copied the number of vowels.**

Comment: You need to count them in separate variables, here you are using `total` for counting both

Comment: Thank you so much guys, I appreciate it. It is working now :]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
        int totalVowels = 0;
        int totalConsonants = 0;
        int wordCount = 0, index = 0;
        var vowels = new HashSet<char> { 'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u' };
        var consonants = new HashSet<char> { 'b', 'c', 'd', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'v', 'x' };

        for (int i = 0; i < sentence.Length; i++)
        {
                if (vowels.Contains(sentence[i]))
                {
                    totalVowels++;
                }
                else if (consonants.Contains(sentence[i]))
                {
                    totalConsonants++;
                }

            }
            Console.WriteLine("Your total number of vowels is: {0}", totalVowels);
            Console.WriteLine("Number of consonants: {0}", totalConsonants);
            Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you need to consider a few things to achieve your target. The input string may or may not contain other characters (special characters or digits), so you should check each character in the input string exists in either `vowels` or in `consonants`, and one more thing, you have to keep separate counters for `vowels` and `consonants`, named `vowelsCount`, `consonantsCount` for instance. Which means if the character is present in the collection of `vowels` then `vowelsCount` should be increased and if it is present in `consonants` then `consonantsCount` should be increased.

Additionally you can keep another variable to take count of non-alphabetic characters if needed. Now take a look into the following code:

```
int vowelsCount = 0, consonantsCount = 0, otherCharacterCount = 0;
string inputSenctnse = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();
var vowels = new HashSet<char> { 'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u' };
var consonants = new HashSet<char> { 'b', 'c', 'd', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'v', 'x' };
foreach (char letter in inputSenctnse)
{
    if (vowels.Contains(letter))
        vowelsCount++;
    else if (consonants.Contains(letter))
        consonantsCount++;
    else
        otherCharacterCount++;

}
Console.WriteLine("Your total number of vowels is: {0}", vowelsCount);
Console.WriteLine("Number of consonants: {0}", consonantsCount);
Console.WriteLine("Other characters : {0}", otherCharacterCount);
Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use two variables to keep both numbers as Vinh Vu.

I just post here another solution but still you need **two** variables to keep both of them:

```
int total = 0;
int wordCount = 0, index = 0;
var vowels = new HashSet<char> { 'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u' };
var consonants = new HashSet<char> { 'b', 'c', 'd', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'v', 'x' };
var sentence = "my sentence";
var vowelCount = sentence.ToCharArray().Where(x => vowels.Contains(x)).Count();
var consonantCount = sentence.ToCharArray().Where(x => consonants.Contains(x)).Count();
```

Answer (score 0):

Initiate another variable name. Here I added the variable total2.

```
int total = 0; 
int total2 = 0;
        int wordCount = 0, index = 0;
        var vowels = new HashSet<char> { 'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u' };
        var consonants = new HashSet<char> { 'b', 'c', 'd', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'v', 'x' };

        for (int i = 0; i < sentence.Length; i++)

                if (vowels.Contains(sentence[i]))
                {
                    total++;
                }
                else if (consonants.Contains(sentence[i]))
                {
                    total2++;
                }

            }
            Console.WriteLine("Your total number of vowels is: {0}", total);
            Console.WriteLine("Number of consonants: {0}", total2);
            Console.ReadLine();
```